# How can I make sure my requests are executed in the order I want

Tags: javascript

I have two functions executing requests on my API:

```
async function requestUtilisateurEdit() {
  urlAPI = baseURL + "/utilisateur/" + idUtilisateurURL;
  let requestUtilisateurEdit = $.ajax({
    type: "GET", // Méthode à employer POST, GET, PUT, DELETE
    url: urlAPI, // Cible du script coté serveur à appeler
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Entreprise: sousdomaine,
    },
  });
  requestUtilisateurEdit.done(function(output_success) {
    let result = output_success.result;
    if (result == 0) {
      setAlert("danger", "Pas d'utilisateur trouvé")
    } else {
      utilisateur = output_success.utilisateur;
    }
  });
  requestUtilisateurEdit.fail(function(http_error) {
    setAlert("danger", http_error.statusText);
  });
  requestUtilisateurEdit.always(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
  });
}

function requestGroupeEdit() {
  urlAPI = baseURL + "/groupe";
  let requestGroupe = $.ajax({
    type: "GET", // Méthode à employer POST, GET, PUT, DELETE
    url: urlAPI, // Cible du script coté serveur à appeler
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Entreprise: sousdomaine,
    },
  });
  requestGroupe.done(function(output_success) {
    let result = output_success.result;
    if (result == 0) {
      setAlert("danger", "Pas de groupe trouvé")
    } else {
      groupe = output_success.groupe;
      setListGroup();
    }
  });
  requestGroupe.fail(function(http_error) {
    setAlert("danger", http_error.statusText);
  });
  requestGroupe.always(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
  })
}
```

I want my first request to be done before my second one starts.
I use async on my first function, then I do that:

```
requestUtilisateurEdit().then(requestGroupeEdit);
```

However, sometimes my second request will be done before my first one.
[image]

How can I make sure my requests are executed in the order I want.

Comment: Use async/await so that your second function will wait for the first one to finish before running `async function fetchData() { await requestUtilisateurEdit(); requestGroupeEdit(); }` then run `fetchData` to start the process

Comment: @ChrisG ty for your answer, however it is not working as my second request can still be executed first sometimes

Comment: can you try defining both functions as async and then inside fetchData call them both with await?

Comment: @ChrisG I just found my answer, since I was using jQuery for my requests , I had to use async : false as one of my parameters :
Should be other way to do it but it's the one that worked for me , ty for your answers anyway

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting `async:false` for your ajax request tho. It is a bad practice for several reasons. It could cause UI freezing, performance issues and Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated, this could cause errors, warnings

Comment: @ChrisG I can see my page is struggling a bit to load now indeed, I think I will let it like that for now because I tried a lot of things that didnt seem to work, if I find another solution I will change and post it here

Comment: "*I use async on my first function*" - that won't be enough if you don't also actually `await` the jQuery ajax promise inside the first function